# SQL is not working on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, pymysql

I am updating an existing MySQL table with pymysql but failed. The error is:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY

And my code is here:

```
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = '''
        INSERT INTO `Tag` (`title`,`weight`) VALUES (%s,%s)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY 
        UPDATE
        title = VALUES(title),
        weight = VALUES(weight)
    '''
    L1 = ['ins', 'ig', 'twitter', 'tiktok', 'ig']
    values = list(set([(item, L1.count(item)) for item in L1]))
    cursor.executemany(sql, values)

    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Can you share your table definition `show create table Tag;`

Comment: @SelVazi Result:  
CREATE TABLE `Tag` (
 `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `workshopid` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `platform` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `weight` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

Comment: Its working fine in my local !